# Why adding sticky to CSS drop down menu breaks it?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, sticky

There are many similar examples, but none I found to deal with this issue.  I'm trying to make <nav> bar with drop-down menu to be sticky. I have a <nav> bar with many menu entries, but I simplified it as much as possible to see where it breaks. There is simple example from w3schools, modified a bit, and it stops working as soon as I add `position:sticky` (you can see it commented out bellow) 
So example code in one file for practicality is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  font-size: 28px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
/*  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
/*  position: sticky; */  /* If enabled it breaks dropdown menu */
  top: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a, .mDrop {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mDrop li:nth-of-type(-n+1) { float: down; }
.mDrop {
    position: relative;
    top:    13.6rem;

}

li .mDrop {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 8rem;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: none;
}

li a:hover, .mDrop:hover .li:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

li:hover > ul,
li:focus-within > ul,
li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {   clear: both; width: 100%; }

.active {  background-color: #4CAF50;   }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a>
  <ul class="mDrop">
    <li><a href="#news">Drop1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Drop2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">Drop3</a></li>
  </ul>
  </li>  
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
</ul>

<h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
<p>The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<div style="Height:80vh"></div>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried many different options examples and no luck.  I **don't** want to encapsulate entire content area in separate <div>, just would like adding stickiness to working drop-down menu.  I also would like solution with CSS/HTML only. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"? Can you share a screenshot of the "broken" state?

Comment: @Shahriar when I enable 'position: sticky', then drop-down menu is not shown any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dropdown is broken because you are giving `position: sticky` to the `ul` tag. Since you have two nested `ul`s in your code, the style is applied to both of them.

```html
<ul> <!-- first ul -->
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a>
        <ul class="mDrop"> <!-- second ul -->
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>  
    ...
    ...
</ul>
```

## Solution

First of all, wrap your `ul` (navbar) in a `<nav>` element. Don't be afraid of "adding another div". This makes you HTML code more semantic and more readable, no need to say it's good for SEO too.

```html
 <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a>
        <ul class="mDrop">
          <li><a href="#news">Drop1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">Drop2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">Drop3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

REMOVE these parts from your CSS:

```css
ul {
    position: -webkit-sticky; /* remove */
    position: sticky; /* remove */
    top: 0; /* remove */
}
```

ADD these to your CSS:

```
.navbar {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```css
li .mDrop {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px; /* I just added these line. Replace 40px with any value that fits your design */
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: none;
}
```

What I'm basically doing is changing how you "style" your elements. Never use "pure" or "element" selectors like (h1, h2, p, ul) unless you really want to do some general styling; for example, resetting browser default styles.

## Full Code

```css
body {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.navbar {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky; /* If enabled it breaks dropdown menu */
  top: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.mDrop {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mDrop li:nth-of-type(-n + 1) {
  float: down;
}
.mDrop {
  position: relative;
  top: 13.6rem;
}

li .mDrop {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 8rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: none;
}

li a:hover,
.mDrop:hover .li:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

li:hover > ul,
li:focus-within > ul,
li ul:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4caf50;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="header">
    <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
    <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">News</a>
        <ul class="mDrop">
          <li><a href="#news">Drop1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">Drop2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#news">Drop3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      <li style="float:right"><a href="#help">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <div style="Height:80vh"></div>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>

</body>
```

Comment: I have \<nav tag in my original page, and tried to add sticky to it, but didn't work.  I also updated my simple example, but the sticky navbar is not sticky.  Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @DenisZ, I added the full edited code to my answer. Click "Run Code Snippet" and see the result.

Comment: Thanks @Shahriar its working I went through my code and noticed that I didn't close my \</nav> tag at the end of menu (no "/") so stickiness didn't work.  btw how do you make it that you can "Run code snippet"?

Comment: I also see that it needs to have `top: 0;` defined to be sticky

Comment: @DenisZ, Glad you find my answer useful! For "Run snippet", there's a "snippet" icon next to the image icon in the editor. Also, you may find https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help useful.